# How to set userdata in a session in the model of my login function

Tags: php, codeigniter

When a user logs in they are directed to my `log in` function -- Here is my partially working code. I commented out the parts that I need help with.

## model

```
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    { 
        return $query->row()->f_name;
    }   
        
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

## controller

```
    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $f_name = $this->model_users->can_log_in();
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'name' => $f_name
            );
            
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        
        redirect('account_dashboard');
```

The user's name is in the database table with their email/pw. I want to get the users `f_name` and set it in the session when they log in since the session is a global var.

## view

my header shows their name:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('name');
```

How do I get db_values from the table and pass them along to the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `$query->row()`, it will return the first row from the query results as an object. So, if you need to return the user's first name, which in this case is stored under the `f_name` field, you'll want to write this:

```
return $query->row()->f_name;
```

Then in your controller, you'll have the first name returned from the model function.

```
$f_name = $this->model_name->model_function_name();
$data = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'),
              'is_logged_in' => 1,
              'name' => $f_name
);
```

In case you need more than just the user's first name in your controller, return the whole row from the model function instead.

```
return $query->row();
```

Then in your, controller you can access the returned object (or array if you use `row_array()`), by accessing its properties which will be named based on the fields' name in the database table.

```
$user = $this->model_name->model_function_name();
$f_name = $user->f_name; // Get the user's first name
$other = $user->other; // Get some other information
```

It works the same way too for `row_array()`, but of course, you'll need to do something like `$user['f_name']` instead of `$user->f_name`.

**EDIT:** Also, make sure the model is loaded by the controller, before you try to call its functions.

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

Comment: I implemented your answer exactly as instructed and it just isn't working. No error either. All spelling is correct. Perhaps you missed something? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Could you edit your post with the updated code so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Hey I made the edits. Let me know what else I can try thanks.

Comment: If i move the `$first = $this->model_users->can_log_in();` before the `if($this->form_validation->run())` block i get the following error `Fatal error: Call to a member function can_log_in() on a non-object in `

Comment: @fabio Could you tell me exactly what's wrong with it? You said that there's no error, but exactly what's wrong with it? Is it not displaying the first name? If so, can you do a `var_dump` on `$f_name` in the controller and see if it's empty or not?

Comment: ok var_dump shows all values are set except for the name. it shows for name 'boolean false'

Comment: If the name is empty, then that means the query does not return the desired result. It either returns more than one row, or none whatsoever. So, I guess you might want to think about something to handle that.

Comment: Well the query is supposed to get the name from and return it to the controller. Thats where the problem is. If i set `name => 'fabio'` in the controller. the view works correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17474/discussion-between-kemal-fadillah-and-fabio)